# Why is 0 moved to stack when using return value?

Tags: c, assembly, clang, disassembly, calling-convention

I'm experimenting disassembling `clang` binaries of simple C programs (compiled with `-O0`), and I'm confused about a certain instruction that gets generated.

Here are two empty `main` functions with standard arguments, one of which returns value and other does not:

```
// return_void.c
void main(int argc, char** argv)
{
}

// return_0.c
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    return 0;
}
```

Now, when I disassemble their assemblies, they look reasonably different, but there's one line that I don't understand:

```
return_void.bin:
(__TEXT,__text) section
_main:
0000000000000000    pushq   %rbp
0000000000000001    movq    %rsp, %rbp
0000000000000004    movl    %edi, -0x4(%rbp)
0000000000000007    movq    %rsi, -0x10(%rbp)
000000000000000b    popq    %rbp
000000000000000c    retq

return_0.bin:
(__TEXT,__text) section
_main:
0000000100000f80    pushq   %rbp                
0000000100000f81    movq    %rsp, %rbp          
0000000100000f84    xorl    %eax, %eax          # We return with EAX, so we clean it to return 0
0000000100000f86    movl    $0x0, -0x4(%rbp)    # What does this mean?
0000000100000f8d    movl    %edi, -0x8(%rbp)
0000000100000f90    movq    %rsi, -0x10(%rbp)
0000000100000f94    popq    %rbp
0000000100000f95    retq
```

It only gets generated when I use the function is not void, so I thought that it might be another way to return 0, but when I changed the returned constant, this line didn't change at all:

```
// return_1.c
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    return 1;
}

empty_return_1.bin:
(__TEXT,__text) section
_main:
0000000100000f80    pushq   %rbp
0000000100000f81    movq    %rsp, %rbp
0000000100000f84    movl    $0x1, %eax           # Return value modified
0000000100000f89    movl    $0x0, -0x4(%rbp)    # This value is not modified
0000000100000f90    movl    %edi, -0x8(%rbp)
0000000100000f93    movq    %rsi, -0x10(%rbp)
0000000100000f97    popq    %rbp
0000000100000f98    retq
```

Why is this line getting generated and what is it's purpose?

Comment: Have you tested this with normal functions i.e. functions not called main?

Comment: `main` not having an `int` return type is against the standard for hosted environments. DO not expect any specific behaviour.

Comment: You forbade clang from removing useless code (with `-O0`). Why are you asking about strange code in the assembly?

Comment: [Why does LLVM allocate a redundant variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59610063) talks about the clang internals - functions with multiple return statements get this `retval`.  Your `main` has an explicit `return 0;` *and* the implicit `return 0` at the closing `}`.  [why does main() have '%retval' in '.ll' file LLVM](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69233253) .  Of course enabling optimization would remove this noise, but you asked clang to compile fast instead of making fast asm.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The purpose of that area is revealed by the following code

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    if (rand() == 42)
      return 1;

    printf("Helo World!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

At the start it does

```
movl    $0, -4(%rbp)
```

then the early return looks as follows

```
callq   rand
cmpl    $42, %eax
jne .LBB0_2
movl    $1, -4(%rbp)
jmp .LBB0_3
```

and then at the end it does

```
.LBB0_3:
movl    -4(%rbp), %eax
addq    $32, %rsp
popq    %rbp
retq
```

So, this area is indeed reserved to store the function return value. It doesn't appear to be terribly necessary and it is not used in optimized code, but in `-O0` mode that's the way it works.

Answer (score 2):

clang is making space on the stack for the arguments (registers `edi` and `rsi`) and puts the value 0 on the stack, too, for some reason. I assume that clang compiles your code to an SSA-representation like this:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int a;

    a = 0;
    return a;
}
```

This would explain why a stack slot is allocated. If clang does constant propagation, too, this would explain why `eax` is zeroed out instead of being loaded from `-4(%rbp)`. In general, don't think too much about dubious constructs in *unoptimized* assembly. After all, you forbade the compiler from removing useless code.

Answer (score 1):

```
movl   $0x0,-0x4(%rbp)
```

This instruction stores `0` at `%rbp - 4`. It seems that clang allocates a hidden local variable for an implicit return value from main.

From the clang mailing list:

> Yes.  We allocate an implicit local variable to hold the return value;
>   return statements then just initialize the return slot and jump to the
>   epilogue, where the slot is loaded and returned.  We don't use a phi
>   because the control flow for getting to the epilogue is not
>   necessarily as simple as a simple branch, due to cleanups in local
>   scopes (like C++ destructors).
>
> Implicit return values like main's are handled with an implicit store
>   in the prologue.

Source: http://lists.cs.uiuc.edu/pipermail/cfe-dev/2012-February/019767.html

Comment: `eax` *does* have the return value, not sure where you got this idea about storing it on the stack, especially in the callee's frame that will be destroyed by the time the caller gets control to examine the return value. You seem to be the one confusing it with the return **address**.

Comment: Beside the fact that this is 32 bit ABI for whatever system while the OP clearly use 64 bit system, the return value **is** stored in `EAX/RAX`. You are making confusion :), maybe by the name *Return **address***, the OP question is indeed a good one.

Comment: You both right, I am not sorry I am made a mistake I am updating the answer.  Thank you

Comment: @Giuseppe Pes: On x86 platform stack pointer moves down (to lower memory addresses) as the stack grows. This means that return address is always stored at *positive* offset from the `rsp` value at function start. `-0x4(%rbp)` cannot possibly be the return address in this case.

Comment: It's nice that you are trying to improve your answer but the fact is that it is non relevant. The OP clearly know how the stack and function calls work, it is just wondering (as I am) why there is a move with 0 in body. I think it's better to delete it and write a new one if you know the answer :)

Comment: Nice answer (now) and reference!

Comment: @FUZxxl: Huh? What are you talking about? One more time: on x86 platform return address is pushed into the stack by `call` instruction and thus ends up *above* the `rsp` (at positive offset) at the moment of function entry. If some "ABI" dared to contradict that simple detail, I would immediately order that ABI erased from all existence. (And no SysV ABI, does not contradict it.) So, once again, what are you tryinmg to say and what does it have to do with SysV ABI?

Comment: @AnT The position `-4(%rbp)` refers to is *below* the position `%rbp` points to. It's the same place as `-4(%rsp)` which is *below* the stack pointer. The return address is placed at `8(%rbp)` in OPs assembly, `-4(%rbp)` does not refer to that position. I don't understand what your issue is.

Comment: @FUZxxl: Sigh... Firstly, my original comment referred to the *original* version of this poster's answer (check the edit history). In that old version this answer claimed that `-4(%rbp)` is where the return address is stored. My comment states that `-4(%rbp)` is definitely *not* where the return address is stored, becuase return adress is stored at *positive* offset from `rbp`. Now, you attacked my comment with your "This is bullshit.". What "bullshit" you are talking about is not clear to me at all. I.e. it is actually me who doesn't understand what your issue is.

Comment: @AnT Okay, I misread your comment. I somehow thought that you were referring to the return value, which can indeed be located at `-4(%rbp)` in the SysV ABI.

Comment: @FUZxxl: Now, as you mention it, I suddenly realize that I most liklely misunderstood this answer author's intent. When he said in his answer that `-4(%rsp)` stored the "return address" he probably meant to say that it stored the "return value". The latter is actually correct.

Answer (score 0):

According the the standard (for hosted environments), [5.1.2.2.1](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.1.2.2.1), `main` is required to returrn an `int` result. So do not expect defined behavior if violating this.

Furthermore, `main` is actually _not required to explicitly return `0`; this is implicitly returned if it reaches the end of the function. (Note this is only for `main`, which also does not have a prototype.

Comment: How is this relevant to the question?

Comment: @FUZxxl: Having the signature of `main` not conforming to the standard when discussing the generated code is not relevant for a question which discusses that code?

Comment: Ah yes, I missed the bogus return type OP uses.