# Why the first two lines in the main function in LLVM IR?

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir

main.c

```
int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

clang -S -emit-llvm main.c generates:

```
define dso_local i32 @main() #0 {
%1 = alloca i32, align 4          ; (why?)
store i32 0, i32* %1, align 4     ; (why?)
ret i32 0
}
```

why the first two lines? This also gets generated only for the main function.
(Using clang-12 && LLVM-12)

Comment: Those are typically generated at a time when the compiler does not yet know that they will not be used.

Comment: Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/q/69233253/8925535 ?