# Why does Clang push 0 before argc in main?

Tags: c, assembly, clang, x86-64

On Mac with Apple Clang 12.0.0, I compiled this program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int arc, char * argv[]) {
    puts("Hello, world!");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

And here is the beginning of Clang's translation of **main**:

```
_main:                                  ## @main
    .cfi_startproc
## %bb.0:
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset %rbp, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register %rbp
    subq    $32, %rsp
    movl    $0, -4(%rbp)
    movl    %edi, -8(%rbp)
```

(I left the directives and comments in, although they do not seem relevant.)

Why does Clang have a 4-byte 0 written to -4(%rbp) first, before it copies the content of %rdi (parameter argc) to the stack?  I noticed that GCC (4.8.5 on RH Linux) does not do this.  Thanks!

Comment: Just so you know, there's a *really* big gap between GCC 4.8.5 (released 2015, and which was old and outdated already then) and Clang 12 (released 2021). GCC is up to release 13 now, you might want to compare to more modern variants of GCC, like version 11.1 which was also released in 2021.

Comment: Did you enable optimizations? It looks like the `0` is a temporary for the `EXIT_SUCCESS`. Also note that storing `edi` to the stack is useless as well. So probably optimizations off.

Comment: To expand on the comment by @Jester, unoptimized builds will do stupid things. This can be seen very clearly [when viewing a few more variants side-by-side](https://godbolt.org/z/aqbe6G3Ta).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude In all fairness, plenty of the releases between gcc 5 and gcc 13 were "release new versions just for the heck of it". The endless compiler updates breaking more things than they fix is a pox, gcc used to be a stable compiler rather than a safety hazard. One used to find one compiler bug per year at most, instead of one per month.

Comment: You analyze not optimized output with plenty of noise. Both emit the same code when optimizations are enabled https://godbolt.org/z/Pbc5vb9jY or more interesting https://godbolt.org/z/6e793d4ve

Comment: @Jester: If it were a temporary for `EXIT_SUCCESS` then we'd see a `mov -4(%rbp), %eax` just before the return, [but we don't](https://godbolt.org/z/jdzWvzf4j).  It looks like it really is a completely dead store.

Comment: @NateEldredge: There's an explicit `return 0` in this `main`, so the implicit return 0 at the closing `}` isn't reached.  Looks like a duplicate of [Why is 0 moved to stack when using return value?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31149806).  (And added a couple more duplicates about clang internals.)

Comment: @Jester Yes, optimizations are off.  My goal is not a fast program, my goal is to understand the compiler's behavior.  As for EXIT_SUCCESS, the program does not use that 0, it creates a new 0 with xorl %ecx, %ecx and then (to return) movl %ecx, %eax.  Yes, the program never uses the parameters stored onthe stack — again, optimization is irrelevant to this question.

Comment: @PeterCordes: The first posting to which you refer (https://stackoverflow.com/q/31149806) is relevant.  Thank you.